# There is no option for commenting in IE6

Tags: support, comments, internet-explorer-6

I am using default Windows XP with IE 6.0.2. When i open any question page, only the link and flag options appear—there is no option for commenting.

Comment: Also, were you logged in correctly? If you're not logged in many options are hidden from you because you can't use them - this includes adding comments.

Comment: I was playing with the browser that's in the PlayStation 3 yesterday - got the same result. It does support JavaScript, but I couldn't click "add comment".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We no longer test in IE6.

The minimum browser we support is IE7.

Comment: +1M if I could, I love you guys!

Comment: Maybe you should test the "reading" of content in IE6, but block IE6 users from asking quesions or providing answers with a nice clear error message.

Comment: I appreciate if you tel this information to the IE6 user that they cannot utilize the features of this site until they upgrade their browser. My company hasn't upgraded all system with IE7 or 8 and I am one of those unfortunate users of this site who continuously refreshing the page to check may be after refresh site will apprear fine to me

Comment: for heaven's sake people, do upgrade to a modern browser, or beg your company to do it! IE6 is _ten years old_ now… you are almost guaranteed to get malware using it. More sites should abandon it, like SE did; finally users and/or system administrators will be forced to update.