# IE6 totally broken on chat.stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, status-declined, chat, internet-explorer-6

Does SO intend to support IE6 for chat? Or is it impossible? There are still many IE6 users out there, I think. Especially in some countries that still primarily use Windows XP

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70018/there-is-no-option-for-commenting-in-ie6/70032#70032

Comment: Your last two words are redundant.

Comment: IE6... *SERIOUSLY!*

Answer (score 16):

We looked at the numbers pretty recently when we merged chat.SU and chat.SF into chat.SE, and *even for IE7* the number was pretty low. For IE6, it is another order of magnitude lower.

So on *one hand* the net benefit from supporting IE6 is exceeding (and decreasingly) low; on the *other hand* the effort involved is very significant (let's face it; IE6 is a PITA), and on the *third hand* (*), anything we can do to drive another subtle nail into IE6's coffin is a good thing. Sorry, but it is.

My suggestion; use [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome), [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox), or *just about [anything](http://www.opera.com/) other than IE6*. At worst case, [IE7](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9AE91EBE-3385-447C-8A30-081805B2F90B) or [IE8](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=341c2ad5-8c3d-4347-8c03-08cdecd8852b) work on XP.

*=Jeff uses the VC $$$ to get a productivity bonus via surgery, by gifting us each with extra limbs. Which is fine, except it is snowing here and I can't find gloves in triples.

Comment: We should always support backward compatibility.  While most SO users might not be using IE6, there's probably a lot of the world that does (therefore affecting Stack Exchange sites that aren't computer related).

Comment: Since you've already had links to IE7 and 8, I've added links to the others as well. You're making it too easy to make the wrong choice. `:)`

Comment: @Lance - no, there is a point of obsolescence. IE6 passed that date a long time ago.

Comment: @Kobi - you are quite correct; thanks.

Comment: @Kobi - I *love* the Opera="anything other" ;p

Comment: @Marc, it may be past that point, but it's still used by millions.

Comment: Chrome does _not_ require admin privs to install. Just saying.

Comment: @Lance - how about a compromise; how about we *detect* IE6 and re-educate those users?

Comment: @Lance: Millions of people get drunk off their ass every night, too. Doesn't mean time should be invested in supporting their stupidity.

Comment: @Lance: Support such outdated clients is a *significant* overhead and limitation - at some point you need to draw the line.

Comment: @Nicholas, erhm, is that a feature request? :)

Comment: @Marc, __LOL, that's a great idea!__

Comment: Millions of users around the world are locked on IE6 (at `$WORK`) due to corporate restrictions. I run XP on my netbook and have IE8, but the work machines I've had have been fixed on IE6

Comment: @Marc Gravell - there *used* to be a site called `end6.org` that many sites redirected to if they detected you running IE6. I quit frequenting those websites when I couldn't get to them any more: it seemed like they didn't care about a lot of users

Comment: If you buy 3 pairs of gloves, then you'll have 2 sets. You guys have VC $$$ anyways, right?

Comment: @Jon - ok, I've looked at the glove line 3 times and I don't understand it. Can you make is clearer for me?

Comment: See the footnote in your post. :)

Comment: @Jon - agh, right; makes sense now - thanks

Comment: @Warren: Yes some users are stuck on the buggy full-of-security-holes IE6 which has no support for current standards; but perhaps when enough web sites cease to fully function and/or enough of these companies get hacked, said companies will finally get a clue and create a policy to keep software at least *reasonably* up to date.

Comment: @Jon - if you buy 3 pairs, you end up with two non-matching sets: Right-Left-Left and Right-Right-Left - not too practical, unless you trade one set with another person, depending on their direction. Stop me when this becomes too silly.

Comment: @Software Monkey - not saying the chat feature should be supported on IE6 - just that it's still use in a VERY widespread way (sadly)

Comment: @Warren: I disagree that it's in *very* widespread use; and where it still is, it's my opinion that it is inexcusable.