# Unable to add comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the error today in question.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84401/what-is-the-error-today-in-question-js)

I am unable to add comments on the stackoverflow.com website.
Is everyone facing javascript issues on the site?

I'm getting "Stackoverflow.questions is null or not an object."

Comment: No. Try flushing your cache. Also which OS and browser are you running?

Comment: No repro here, I just made a test comment on a question of mine. Did any of your settings change, or maybe this is only having an issue on a particular question?

Comment: Perhaps related, but [someone else is poking up about question.js](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84401/what-is-the-error-today-in-question-js). I'm not experiencing any issue on my machine (IE8/XP).

Comment: Runs smooth on Chrome/Win7 here

Comment: Regarding your update, I'm seeing a very similar line in the question.js question I linked earlier. Perhaps you're running into the same issue as that user is.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've cleared your cache.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same issue - running on IE6 on Win2003 (yes, I know its old but it a corporate thin client desktop which I cannot upgrade :( ).

It also occurs here on meta.  I tried adding this as a comment, but the script error means the "add comment" button is unresponsive.  (As are the upvote, favorite etc buttons...)

EDIT: Also fails on IE7 on Win2003.  With the same error.
I've cleared the cache but to no avail....

Comment: [IE6 is no longer officially supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70018/there-is-no-option-for-commenting-in-ie6/70032#70032).

Comment: In _theory_, the latest info on browser support will always be located [in this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported/71208#71208).

Comment: This affected IE7 (and lower); it's fixed now.