# What is the error today in question.js

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow

Today, I started getting errors in StackOverflow
IE8 in compatibility mode

Hers is the question I was viewing (url)
[Strange scrollTop() bug (in some browsers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290254/strange-scrolltop-bug-in-some-browsers)

Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 1
Char: 18794
Code: 0
URI: http://sstatic.net/js/question.js?v=3ee78a262729

THEN

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; MDDR; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0)
Timestamp: Wed, 23 Mar 2011 13:05:16 UTC

Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 1
Char: 18794
Code: 0
URI: http://sstatic.net/js/question.js?v=3ee78a262729

Message: 'StackExchange.question' is null or not an object
Line: 28
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: [Strange scrollTop() bug (in some browsers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290254/strange-scrolltop-bug-in-some-browsers)

Message: Object expected
Line: 420
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: [Strange scrollTop() bug (in some browsers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290254/strange-scrolltop-bug-in-some-browsers)

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: https://stackexchange.com/ads/launched-question/js?id=SE20-ad-container

THEN
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; MDDR; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0)
Timestamp: Wed, 23 Mar 2011 13:05:33 UTC

Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 1
Char: 18794
Code: 0
URI: http://sstatic.net/js/question.js?v=3ee78a262729

Message: 'StackExchange.question' is null or not an object
Line: 28
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: [Strange scrollTop() bug (in some browsers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290254/strange-scrolltop-bug-in-some-browsers)

Message: Object expected
Line: 420
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: [Strange scrollTop() bug (in some browsers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290254/strange-scrolltop-bug-in-some-browsers)

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: https://stackexchange.com/ads/launched-question/js?id=SE20-ad-container

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; MDDR; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0)
Timestamp: Wed, 23 Mar 2011 13:06:20 UTC

Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 1
Char: 18794
Code: 0
URI: http://sstatic.net/js/question.js?v=3ee78a262729

Message: 'StackExchange.question' is null or not an object
Line: 28
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: [Strange scrollTop() bug (in some browsers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290254/strange-scrolltop-bug-in-some-browsers)

Message: Object expected
Line: 420
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: [Strange scrollTop() bug (in some browsers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290254/strange-scrolltop-bug-in-some-browsers)

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: https://stackexchange.com/ads/launched-question/js?id=SE20-ad-container

Comment: The answer is simple: quit using IE8.  `:P`

Comment: I don't get to dictate the browser choice :) - those customers unwilling to move from IE6 make it fun!

Comment: You could've just turned off compatibility mode, though :)

Comment: Have to have it on for some old IE code still in use that we have not yet updated in the major use of the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic "trailing comma" bug; as thus it only affected IE7. Fixed now.

Comment: yay!  I can comment once again!